# Как сделать обновляемую информацию в Tkinter

Tags: python, psutil

Есть простейший код, пускай собирает данные о загрузке процессора.
Он выводит информацию в консоль, которая обновляется каждые 5 секунд,
хочется, что бы он выводился в окно Tkinter.
Проблема заключается, в том. что, при запуске этого кода, окно зависает.
Выполняется только код проверки производительности процессора.
Как это можно исправить, что бы и окно Tk было в рабочем состояние, и процесс не останавливался, и выводил информацию на экран.
Я тут пару строк написал, если пожожите, будет очень круто.

```
    import psutil                                          
    import threading
        CPU = 0
        def start():
            from time import sleep
            while True:
                CPU = psutil.cpu_percent()
                print(CPU,'%', flush=True)
                sleep(5)
from tkinter import *                                                            
tk = Tk()                                                                       
tk.title("CPU")                                            
tk.geometry("1280x720+320+60")
bl = Button(tk,command = start)                                   
bl.place(x=200,y=500, width=200, height=50) 
tk.mainloop()
```

Я просто не знаю, как через (наверное)
label это можно реализовать
bl = Label(tk, text = CPU)
Проверить не могу, так как зависает окно Tk, возможно вы сможете мне помочь.

Comment: смотрите в сторону `threading`

Comment: Отформатируйте, пожалуйста, код. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks